# Update md5 checksum when files are modified

Tags: server, md5sum

I have a server that when the contents of a specific folder are modified it will calculate a checksum.

The problem is that the calculation of the checksum takes about 30 minutes since it is recalculating every single file in that folder even if a simple text file has been modified. So while the checksum is running the files are not to be used.

The calculation of the checksum is done with the following command.

`find . -type f | xargs md5sum > some_file`

Every day new files are added to the folder and others are deleted.

**Is there a way to update the checksum file only on the modified/added/deleted files without calculating the md5 for the rest of the files?**

Edit: Clarification

The checksum needs to contain an md5 for every single file in that folder. What I am trying to achieve is a way to edit/update the checksum file when something changes in the folder:

1. Remove md5 for file when deleted
2. Add md5 for file when added in folder
3. Update hash code when file is modified

All these without recalculating the entire folder from the top

Comment: Look at `-mtime` option for find. That will allow you to find files modified within some time. `find . -type f -mtime -1` will find files modified within the last day (24 hours).

Comment: @SorenA Yes, but how `mtime` will help me edit the "updates" in the checksum file? I don't think it will do what i want. What I am trying to achieve is to edit the contents of the md5 with the modified files. So if a file is deleted, remove it from the checksum, if a file is added, add it to the checksum, if a file is edited, update the hash for that specific file.

Comment: @SorenA unless `mtime` will be used to create a checksum of the modified files only and combined with a `sed` or `awk` the checksum file is edited. Can `mtime` show deleted files as well?

Comment: `mtime` let's you find the modified files and calculate checksum for only them. There are no way, that I know of, to show deleted files. You will have to run through your filelist to se if they exists, with something like `if test -f $filename ... ` and then build a new output file with the file that exists plus the newly found ones.

Comment: @SorenA I was hoping that a more straightforward approach would be possible. Like an md5sum option that will check for changes only. But a combination of commands seems to be able to do this. I have subfolders in there that can be divided into chunks. And basically calculate the checksum for the modified subfolder only and append it in the master checksum. Basically when a file is added in the sub the oldest version is removed (think of it as backup) so a checksum in the subf will save some time. Then with `sed` it will be easy to replace the lines for that subf

Comment: You might use some scripting: Add filename and timestamp to every row in your md5 file, then when the folder has been modified walk through that md5-file, forget the line when the file in question does notexist any longer, create new hash when the timestamp of the file has changed, and otherwise leave the information alone. You might not want to modify the md5-file, but first move it to a backup file, walk through that and write to a new file.

Comment: @ridgy well yes, that seems to be the way to go. I will need to do a lot of testing before going live. Hoping that it will save a massive amount of time.

Comment: A simpler solution: `find` has the test `-newer <file>`. So if you issue `find . -type f -newer <md5file> -print0 | xargs -0 md5sum >> <md5file>` this will only create hashes for the files modified since the last modification of `<md5file>`. I use `-print0` and `-0` options here, as filenames may contain special characters and blanks. There is a chance of not getting a file this way when it is modified while the process runs; it's up to you to see this as a risk. But this does not delete lines of deleted files or older lines of modified files, so this would still be the task for a script.

Comment: @ridgy Thanks I will give it a try. I am not worried of modification during the process since they will be locked until it finishes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very rough script trying to do what you want to. Feel free to copy, modify, optimize - would be nice to have some response if it works for you. If have tested in my "Downloads" folder and found only one error left (a filename containing `[`, which `grep`did not like).

**Edit:** Modified the source again, as the creation of timestamps (in the first version) is no longer needed as new/modified files are found with `find -newer`. Also added parameters to setthe name of the hash file and possibly the top folder to start with; so the script does not have to be called from the top directory.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Script to create md5 hashes for files in and below the current directory
# or the directory passed at the commandline
# In the first run, create the sums for all files.
# In the second run,
#  - if the files have not changed, keep the entries
#  - if the files have been deleted, forget the entry
#  - if the files have changed, create new md5 hash.
#
# Rough version - should be optimized
#

if [ $# -lt 1 ] ; then
  echo "Usage:"
  echo "$0 <hashfile> [<topdir>]"
  echo
  exit
fi

export HASHFILE=$1
export TOPDIR='.'
if [ $# -eq 2 ] ; then TOPDIR=$2; fi

export BACKFILE=$HASHFILE.bck
export TMPFILE=$HASHFILE.tmp

# In the first run, we create the file $HASHFILE if it does not exist
# You have to make sure that $HASHFILE does not contain any garbage for the first run!!

if [ ! \( -f $HASHFILE -a -s $HASHFILE \) ]; then
  echo -n "Creating $HASHFILE for the first time..."
  find $TOPDIR -type f -print0 | xargs -0 md5sum > $HASHFILE
  echo "done."
  exit
fi

# In the second run, we proceed to find the differences.
# First, find the newer files

find $TOPDIR -type f -newer $HASHFILE -print > $TMPFILE

# Now save the old file and create a new one, starting with new files

mv $HASHFILE $BACKFILE
echo -n "Processing new or modified files ..."
cat $TMPFILE | while read filename ; do
  md5sum "$filename" >> $HASHFILE
done
echo "done."

# Now walk through the old file and process to new file

cat $BACKFILE | while read md5 filename ; do
  # Does the file still exist?
  if [ -f "$filename" ] ; then
    # Has the file been modified?
    if grep -q -e "^$filename$" $TMPFILE ; then 
      echo "$filename has changed!"
    else
      echo "$md5  $filename" >> $HASHFILE
      #echo "$filename has not changed."
    fi
  else
    echo "$filename has been removed!"
  fi
done

# We now may delete temporary files
# rm $BACKFILE
# rm $TMPFILE

exit
```

Comment: Thanks. I will look into this after new year's though and will let you know. At first glance it seems right and to the point. I am not worried about special characters since files will have the same prefix and the names consist of numbers and letters. It's a pity though that md5sum does not have an option to update the checksums. Till now if I change a 50kb text file I need to recalculate the checksum for the entire 150Gb folder

Comment: (1/2) I have used it in a test environment and works fine. It takes a lot less to calculate the checksum for the entire folder now. I made some alterations though. The master folder contains several subfolders that go 3 levels down (no files in between). Each subfolder at the bottom level contains a checksum of the files in that folder (for validation). Now when something changes in that folder a new checksum is created.

Comment: (2/2) The contents of each checksum are then catted into the master checksum at the top level. It needs a little bit more QA to see whether there are issues in that approach but it generally works.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a script called RDChecksum that is able to update file checksums based on the 'last modified' timestamps:

https://github.com/rdiez/Tools/tree/master/RDChecksum